# Passing Object as Argument between Fragments

Tags: java, android

[image]

This is the Object diagram from the book Big Nerd Ranch Guide - Android Programming. It is for an app that has a list-detail structure.

Here the CrimeLab class holds the ArrayList of the objects that are displayed in the CrimeListFragment. When an item in that ListView is clicked, the Id field of that Crime object is passed to the CrimeActivity which opens the details of that Crime object in the Crime Fragment.

CrimeFragment calls the getCrime(UUID) method of the CrimeLab class to get a reference to that particular Crime object.

My question is, would this be considered the best approach of passing an object's field to another activity and then that activity retrieving the object via the field Extra provided. Should we instead make the Crime class Serializable and directly pass the Crime object from one fragment/activity to another?

Which approach would be considered better and more efficient? Or does it not matter?

I'm sorry if this is a naive question.

Comment: When building an app that reads from a database or a webservice, you will want to pass just the id or url. This way you can open the Fragment from anywhere by just passing a long (or a String) and you won't need to build the object before opening the Fragment.
This way your code will be much more testable and you will have to find bugs for object creation in just one place (the destination Fragment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With serialization, the object retrieved by the second activity would be an **identical, but different** object. That means any modification you do on the object in `CrimeFragment` would not be reflected in the `CrimeLab` ArrayList, and would be lost once you exit the fragment.

The best approach depends on what you want to do with the object, and the cost of retrieval. In your case, the cost of serialization / deserialization would most certainly outweight the cost of accessing an ArrayList.

Also, implementing Parcelable should be prefered over Serializable on Android for performance reason.

Comment: Thank you! That clears it up. I actually have an idea how Serialization works in Java but it didn't occur to me to connect the dots in this context.